# Amazon Product Advertising API for Asp.net & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, soap, amazon-web-services

I want to fetch books using Amazon Product Advertising API with asp.net and C#. All the guides and codes are so confusing as to they don't give you a single method to search the books.
Is there any single stub that can be used to call the service and fetch the books based on the ISBN.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a good sample solution you can download.
http://aws.amazon.com/code/2480?_encoding=UTF8&queryArg=searchQuery&x=0&fromSearch=1&y=0&searchPath=code&searchQuery=Advertising

They give you a class called SignedRequestHelper, then you make a call like this:

```
   public static void Main()
        {
            SignedRequestHelper helper = new SignedRequestHelper(MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY, DESTINATION);

            /*
             * The helper supports two forms of requests - dictionary form and query string form.
             */
            String requestUrl;
            String title;

            /*
             * Here is an ItemLookup example where the request is stored as a dictionary.
             */
            IDictionary<string, string> r1 = new Dictionary<string, String>();
            r1["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
            r1["Version"] = "2009-03-31";
            r1["Operation"] = "ItemLookup";
            r1["ItemId"] = ITEM_ID;
            r1["ResponseGroup"] = "Small";

            /* Random params for testing */
            r1["AnUrl"] = "http://www.amazon.com/books";
            r1["AnEmailAddress"] = "foobar@nowhere.com";
            r1["AUnicodeString"] = "αβγδεٵٶٷٸٹٺチャーハン叉焼";
            r1["Latin1Chars"] = "ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳ";

            requestUrl = helper.Sign(r1);
            title = FetchTitle(requestUrl);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Method 1: ItemLookup Dictionary form.");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Title is \"" + title + "\"");
            System.Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You need to use the ItemLookup (like the example) but set the IdType to ISBN.  Then set the ItemId to the actual ISBN.   Here are the details on ItemLookup:

docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?ItemLookup.html

Comment: Pity there's nothing about ItemSearchRequest in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I get this when I use that sample. looks like there has been a change in the API recently.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML document. ---> Sy
stem.InvalidOperationException: <ItemLookupResponse xmlns='http://webservices.am
azon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01'> was not expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch books install this library (Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/

Example:

```cs
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication("accesskey", "secretkey");
var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.UK);
var result = await client.GetItemsAsync("978-0261102385");
```